# Why is this.tick not a number?

Tags: javascript

Why is this.tick not a number in this script?

```
var universe;

$(function() {
    universe = new Universe();

    universe.timeStart();
});

function Universe() {       
    this.timer = 0;
    this.tick = 0;
    this.timeStart = function(){
        this.timer = setInterval(this.timeForward, 500);
    };
    this.timeStop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    };
    this.timeForward = function(){
        this.tick++;
        console.log(this.tick);
    };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qhL492w1/

Comment: Context issue. `setInterval`'s function argument doesn't call in the context of Universe Instance. https://jsfiddle.net/oLdnjux1/

Comment: because `this` inside timeFoward is referring to the window, not your object

Comment: Change to `this.timer = setInterval(this.timeForward.bind(this), 500);` or use arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use an arrow function to preserve the execution context that the keyword `this` points to, so once the function that you're making setTimeout/setInterval call gets triggered, `this` will be the global scope.

(if you're running this in the browser, `this` will be `window` by the time the timeout/interval resolves. You can verify that by doing a `console.log(this)` in your code).

If you need `this` to stay the same, use an arrow function to make sure that `this` keeps pointing at what it's pointing to when you *declare* the code, rather than when the code *executes*: `setInterval(() => this.timeForward(), 500)`.

Also, modern browsers support modern JS, with consts and class syntax, so what you're doing in a function may make more sense written as:

```
class Universe() {      
  constructor() {  
    this.timer = 0;
    this.tick = 0;
  }

  timeStart(){
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.timeForward(), 500);
  }

  timeStop() {
    if (this.timer) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }

  timeForward() {
    this.tick++;
    console.log(this.tick);
  }
}

const universe = new Universe();
universe.timeStart();
```

And then loading that with a `<script src="yourfile.js" defer></script>`, where the `defer` keyword basically does the same thing that jQuery's `$(...)` does: it runs the code in your file only after the DOM is done (but before DOMContentLoaded gets triggered), no matter where in the HTML you place that script tag.